# Pydev Debugger not working with breakpoints

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I have a simple test module:

```
print("fish")
print("sticks")
```

It runs pretty fast as expected, wether i use **Run as** or **Debugg as** does not matter.

But as soon as I enter a Breakpoint the Debugger starts (pydev debugger: starting (pid: 2696)) but does not reach the breakpoint nor finish the program(>5min).

I suddenly had this problem in a bigger project and created this test module to see if the debugger works. I did not change any settings in the prefrences menu of eclipse. I'm using python 3.x with the anaconda interpreter.

I restarted the computer and updated eclipse and pydev.

Answer (score 3):

I found that deleting .metadata from the workspace solves the problem. But I have no clue what caused the issue.

Comment: This deleted all settings (compiler settings, editor settings, ...) perhaps it's worth to try to find out if there's a specific part of .metadata that can be deleted

Comment: I had to remove the workspace.xml file, inside the .idea folder